# Show that the map is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

I have a doubt in part $(3)$

Clearly this map is surjective using part $(b).$

To show injectiveness, let $x\neq y$

To show: $M_x\neq M_y$

Now as we are working in a Hausdroff space so singletons are closed, therefore Define a map $f:X\to [0,1]$
as $f(x)=0 $ and $f(y)=1$. (Using Urysohn's Lemma)

Then $f\in M_x$

But now how to show $f\notin M_y$?

And please also provide some hint for part $(d)$, I am unable to crack that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your doubt in (c): if $\;f(y)=1\neq0\implies f\notin M_y\;$ and we've finished. About part (d) I (still) don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already comment, in your example $\;f(y)=1\neq0\implies f\notin M_y\;$ .

As for (d): what fails is (b). If you already did the proof for (b) in the given case of $\;X\;$ compact then you probably went the usual way: choose open intervals where some functions don't vanish by continuity, then take a *finite* cover and define a function that doesn't vanish anyway but it belongs to an ideal, contradiction and etc.

Now you're going to do something similar but you'll prove there's a maximal ideal which isn't of the form $\;M_x\;$ , for any $\;x\in X\;$. Look at page $\;3\;$ in http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH403-MaxIdeals.pdf

I think this solves your problem.